# Ansible shell command `pod2man` not found

Tags: shell, ansible, archlinux, pacman-package-manager

I'm trying to install pacaur using a script via Ansible:

```
curl -s https://gist.githubusercontent.com/Tadly/0e65d30f279a34c33e9b/raw/pacaur_install.sh | bash
```

With the ansible command

```
ansible 192.168.1.2 -m shell -a "curl -s https://gist.githubusercontent.com/Tadly/0e65d30f279a34c33e9b/raw/pacaur_install.sh | bash"
```

But I get  `pacman` complaining about `pod2man` missing. It seems to be a problem with the PATH of ansible command.

Running the command on the machine directly using ssh  works correctly.

---

Here's the output of: `ansible -m all shell -a 'echo $PATH'`

```
localhost | SUCCESS | rc=0 >>
/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/lib/jvm/default/bin:/usr/bin/site_perl:/usr/bin/vendor_perl:/usr/bin/core_perl

192.168.1.2| SUCCESS | rc=0 >>
/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin
```

Comment: Does this need to be done in an ad-hoc way (in which case the fastest way to address it is to ssh in and install it manually), or are you ok with writing a playbook?  Have you tried using [`command`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/command_module.html) or [`shell`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/shell_module.html#shell) instead?  What about running a script that first echos out the `PATH`?

Comment: more likely PATH of sudo. pacaur_install.sh calls pacman through sudo. It appears, that pod2man is not in sudo's PATH. You need to either adjust the install script to set PATH in the sudo call or adjust the PATH in sudoers.

Comment: @XiongChiamiov the reason why I need ansible is that in reality I need to install that on several machines :). I however posted the result of the script echoing the `PATH`

@sborsky That seems to be the reason. [this](http://serverfault.com/questions/734560/ansible-become-user-not-picking-up-path-correctly) question seems related. Even though with normal ssh I get the right `PATH`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As reported in comments, the problem is that when switching users `sudo` sanitizes `PATH` (see [this ServerFault question](https://serverfault.com/questions/734560/ansible-become-user-not-picking-up-path-correctly) for details).

The ad-hoc command to export the local `PATH` to hosts that I propose seems a bit hacky but it works (it uses the `--extra-vars` option of `ansible` command together with Jinja's variable injection)

```
ansible all -m shell -a "export PATH={{path}}; curl -s https://gist.githubusercontent.com/Tadly/0e65d30f279a34c33e9b/raw/pacaur_install.sh | bash" -e path=$PATH
```

You could also use the `{{ lookup('env', 'PATH') }}` to forward the `PATH`.

Answer (score 1):

The `free-form` parameter of the [script module](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/script_module.html) expects

> path to the local script file followed by optional arguments.

So `ansible 192.168.1.2 -m script -a "https://gist.githubusercontent.com/Tadly/0e65d30f279a34c33e9b/raw/pacaur_install.sh"` should not work. It should work if you download the script on your Ansible control host and set the free-form parameter to the local path of the script.

Comment: You are right. I pasted the wrong ansible command. Now I edited the question body. Sorry and thank you.

Comment: Have you checked that the script is executable?

Comment: Also `script` is the correct module than. `shell` module is propably better.

Comment: You're right. I edited the body accordingly after testing the right command. Still having the issue.

Comment: You need to set the `PATH`via http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/playbooks_environment.html or set the full path in the script.